# an item on bottom navigation is not changed

Tags: android

i implemented Webview and bottom navigation
and i want the pages move in the webview when i click the items of bottom navigation
but when i selected an item on bottom navigation
the selected status does not change
the first one is checked always ..
it is fixed and never be changed
please help me...
here is my code

enter code here

```
MainActivity
  
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                showToast();
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
        }else{
          
            getProviders();
           
            getLocation();
        }


        layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        vView = findViewById(R.id.wView);

        webSettings = vView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        vViewlayout  =  vView.getLayoutParams();

        vView.loadUrl("https://devchannel.co.kr/");

        vView.addJavascriptInterface(new Bridge(),"android");

        webViewClient = new WebClient();
        webChromeClient = new webChrome();

        vView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        vView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

       
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }




        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavBar);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    Log.d("Item id",""+item);
                    Log.d("check????? ",""+bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).isChecked());
                    Log.d("check????? ",""+bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).isChecked());
                    Log.d("check????? ",""+bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).isChecked());
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.chatting: {
                        vView.loadUrl("https://devchannel.co.kr/chat/m/chat_list");
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.channelquest: {
                        vView.loadUrl("https://devchannel.co.kr/quest/m/quest_main");
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.channelvs:{
                        vView.loadUrl("https://devchannel.co.kr/vs/m/vs_main");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });



        }




R.layout.activity_main

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/mainView">

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/wView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      >

                    </WebView>

                    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                        android:id="@+id/bottomNavBar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
                        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"
                        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_color"
                        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_color"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        ></com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
            </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>




navigation_items.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/chatting"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="@string/chatting"
        android:icon="@drawable/chatting">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/channelquest"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="@string/channelquest"
        android:icon="@drawable/channelquest">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/channelvs"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="@string/channelvs"
        android:icon="@drawable/group">
    </item>
</menu>



selector_color.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FF9407" android:state_checked="true"></item>
    <item android:color="#000000" android:state_checked="false"></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
return false;
```

To this:

```
return true;
```

And try once.

**Reason:**

> return true to display the item as the selected item and false if the item should not be selected. Consider setting non-selectable items as disabled preemptively to make them appear non-interactive.